# Zebra and Donkey Watching

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics, photometry

Suppose I have a white donkey in front of me.
Say i paint black stripes on the objective of my camera lens and click a photo of it.
The context of this question is that when we cover a lens horizontally and view an object with it, there is no visible difference in the image formed after and before except the intensity is less.
My question is when we add black bands on the lens, vertically, will only the intensity change or will black stripes appear in the photo.
Will the donkey in my photo actually appear like a zebra? Or will it still remain a white donkey? And why ?

Comment: This will depend on the lens aperture, width of the stripes and the distance of the focal plane. If you are using a really large lens aperture and the donkey is relatively far away, the bands will be spread into blurry blobs, and basically result in lower intensity. The light originating from a certain point on the donkey (presuming that the donkey is in focus and at a reasonable distance) will end up being projected onto a single point on the sensor even if some of those rays are blocked. I.e. imagine [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yxO1.png), but with one of these rays blocked.

Comment: Why don’t you do the experiment and find out?

Comment: The stripes will probably become blurred as in [this picture of blurred leaves in th foreground](https://cdn.fstoppers.com/styles/full/s3/media/2015/12/guid-to-epic-forground-bokeh-vinson-images-trees.jpg) from [this guide on blurred photos](https://fstoppers.com/education/complete-guide-epic-foreground-bokeh-102211).